# MySQL schema, which way is more performant? M-N relation or save all related IDs as a String?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, vuejs2

I am designing MySQL DB for a vocabulary exam.

Table: `users`, `words`, `results`

The participant selects all the words that he/she know its meaning. All exams are different from each other, i.e. an exam is produced randomly from the database. It's **about**  `350`  **words** for every exam.

Now I want to store a result for every exam plus all the words that participant is selected. As you see it is a lot of `ids` (words) for every exam to save!  There are two ways in my mind:

1- ManyToMany Relation in `result_word` table (max 350 rows for every exam):

```
result_id | word_id   
--------------------
    1     |  33
    1     |  12
    .     |   .
    .     |   .
```

2- As a String in a column `answered_ids` in `results` table:

```
    id    | answered_ids   
-------------------------
    1     |  "12,33,..."
```

all ids for result 1: `answered_ids` : `"33,12,..."`

And then when I need them, `explode()` them with php!

I think the second way is better because the first way could become thousands of rows in DB very quickly. Am I right? Or is there a better way?

**UPDATE:**

In this exam, user can see a list of  `English words` randomly selected from `words` table and nothing else! The user clicks on every word he thinks he knows its meaning! Also, There is a `fake_words` table that is 50 words randomly is selected in addition to `actual words` if the user clicks on fake words more than 3 times, the test will fail.  The final result will tell the user how much vocabulary skill he has.

I am creating this app with `VueJs2`. I want to store all the words that user is selected in addition to his exam result. Then when one user wants to see his results, he can see every single word he clicked!

My concern is the following:  Would it be a problem if the number of exams becomes a lot?  5000 for example. Also, any general suggestion for how to implement this app would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends what you are going to do with data afterwards + is this some kind of system that everyone on earth will use?

Comment: @Kyslik, I just want to show list of answered words, nothing else, If it becomes thousands of exams, we will have millions of ids in pivot table, is not it a very slow query after that?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Are you bothered because you think SQL queries will be slow? Are you bothered because you think so many IDs will use too much space? Do you need transferability? Are you going to show only "one exam result" per request?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid of Slow queries not space! there will be one `exam results` for a request, I will update my question

Comment: I will not have transferability

Comment: Also, are you going to save it all in bulk (not recommended since what if user closes the window or whatever users do when they lose their progress) or trying to do some kind of JavaScript frontend that will save data continuously... I am sorry that I bombard you with these questions.

Comment: Woww! I want to create this exam with `vueJs`, I think I have to save data continiusly!!

Comment: I think I have to choose the first way!!  right?

Comment: Let me think for a while I will come back and write my opinion. Could you please also add information with "example" + where is the "question" stored? I kind of do not understand the vocabulary test.

Comment: @Kyslik I updated my question

Comment: Hey, I've read some articles about the topic, and until you are going to be next Facebook do it the M-M relation way. RDBMS is going to cache a lot and it will be fast I assume .5ms queries, and if you gonna use Laravel Eloquent its going to form queries using `WHERE IN`.

Comment: @Kyslik, Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern DBMS's, including MySQL, can handle millions upon millions of rows in tables. You are talking about a very small amount of data. As such, you should go with solution 1.

1. This will allow you to scale the exams up or down automatically, without needing to modify your PHP code.
2. Your text fields in the database will be length constrained, making it possible that you won't be able to fill in all of the `word_id` that you need.
3. You can construct SQL queries to do interesting things with the data, such as average how many words people knew, etc, without having to write PHP code to do so.

If you're concerned about the query speed of large tables, indexes on the data will ensure that your queries run fast enough to be indistinguishable from native objects, even across several table `JOIN` operations. I would suggest [Use The Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/), which provides brass tacks analysis and examples of several different DBMS's and how to best index your data.

Comment: Thank you,   what if I don't need that flexibility?  If it is `4000` exams, my pivot  table will have `1,400,000` rows,  don't you think my queries become very slow?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki, as for flexibility, if you don't think you need flexibility, then just dump everything in your PHP script. The fact that you're here, today, asking this question means that you think you **will** need the flexibility. If it was a trivial problem you were describing, you would have just implemented it by now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time. I  will go with solution 1